# SQL: how to select records that filed content is not sub string of others

Tags: mysql, sql

how to select records that filed content is not sub string of others?

In server side of web application, I want to create some links (title of other contents) automatically like Wikipedia in a long text.
I want to not select strings when one string is sub-string of others:
My table is some thing like this and i want to select

```
id | title_to_wiki_link   | 
---------------------------------------------
1  | title xxxx xxx zzzz  | 1=>yes (is unique)
2  | text xxxx            | 1=>yes (is unique)
3  | title yyyyy          | 1=>yes (is unique)
4  | title                | 0=>no (is part of 3,1)
5  | yyy                  | 0=>no (is part of 3)
6  | zzz                  | 0=>no (is part of 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.title_to_wiki_link not like concat('%', t.title_to_wiki_link, '%')
                 );
```

Note that this will have pretty poor performance, so if your table is large, this may not be feasible.  Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have a good solution for large tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by `LEFT JOIN`ing the table to itself, looking for entries which are not substrings of another title:

```
SELECT l1.*
FROM links l1
LEFT JOIN links l2 ON l2.id != l1.id AND l2.title_to_wiki_link LIKE CONCAT('%', l1.title_to_wiki_link, '%')
WHERE l2.id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
id  title_to_wiki_link
1   title xxxx xxx zzzz
2   text xxxx
3   title yyyyy
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=61751ccf444088d273b8415c9a0c9f73)